# Múltiplos bancos MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

Boa noite.

Estou criando um sistema em PHP que digamos, se assemelha à um Shopping virtual (varias "lojas" e cada loja com seus produtos).

Para isso eu preciso armazenar dados de usuários, lojas, empresas, produtos, horários, dias, pedidos, pagamentos, etc, etc e tal.

Além de tudo isso da interface do usuário, ainda teria a camada de HelpDesk, administração (por parte das lojas), administração do sistema, configurações, analytics, estatísticas e etc.

Então a minha duvida é a seguinte, em termos de desempenho x organização, compensa eu separar essas camadas em banco de dados separados?

Por exemplo, um banco de dados principal com as tabelas essenciais (usuários, lojas, produtos...) e outros bancos com as auxiliares (estatísticas, helpdesk e etc).

Levando em consideração que será comum a consulta entre bancos (buscar um usuário na hora de salvar um ticket no helpdesk e etc).

Isso é viável? Afeta muito o desempenho (todos os bancos no mesmo servidor)? Alguém que já fez isso poderia me contar sobre a sua experiência?

Obrigado.

Comment: Normalmente é usado vários banco de dados para melhor escalabilidade. Se as lojas são independentes e cada um possui seus dados, acredito que o melhor a fazer é que cada loja tenha um banco de dados separado. A vantagem disso é para a manutenção (você pode saber quem usa mais e menos recursos, mover bancos de dados para outro servidor, monitorar backups), isso permite que lojas possuam diferentes versões, ou seja modifica para um mas não para todos. Porém separar dados que entre si possuem sentido EU não considero interessante, porém nunca passei por nenhuma situação desse tipo, então...

Comment: Você pode usar postgresql com schema, por exemplo, as tabelas comuns que você mencionou estariam em um schema geral, e cada loja teria seu próprio schema, com as tabelas que contém informações só para a loja em específico. Assim estaria tudo em um banco apenas e organizado.

Answer (score 1):

Bom, acho melhor você usar vários bancos de dados, para separar informações de cada loja, no caso do seu sistema for um "shopping". Ou seja,, banco 1 para loja 1, banco 2 para loja 2 e assim vai. Entretanto se for uma loja virtual, não acho que deva criar um banco para produtos, outro banco para usuarios, recomendaria um banco só com várias tabelas.